# What disorder might be considered opposite of the Histrionic Personality Disorder?

Tags: personality, abnormal-psychology, personality-disorder, diagnosis, dsm

If a person might be considered the opposite of Narcissistic or having a Histrionic Personality disorder, what might it be called?

For example, a person who feels a need to be unnoticed.

Of course, I mean "disorder" in the sense that these qualities are "disruptive" to a healthy lifestyle...

Maybe some sort of insecurity disorder? Can anti-social disorders somehow fit? What about situations perhaps stemming from PTSD?

> Don't be a target!" -Every military branch, (except maybe the Army).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Diagnosis of [personality disorders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personality_disorder) in general is moving away from a categorical system (patient does or does not have the disorder), to a [dimensional system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional_models_of_personality_disorders) (patient scores extreme on personality traits).  In this system, labels such as HPD and NPD will eventually be deprecated.

The categorical system maps onto scores in the dimensional system as illustrated by [this chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personality_disorder#Versus_normal_personality) (based on the DSM-IV-TR, an older version of the standard diagnostic manual in North America):

[image]

To find the "opposite" (counterpart) of a personality disorder using this chart, just look for a disorder that is red (low) where the counterpart is green (high), and vice versa.  For HPD, it looks like AvPD ([Avoidant Personality Disorder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avoidant_personality_disorder)) is a close match.